# Retrieve Firestore Auto generated Document ID from field

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a Restaurant Delivery app, I'm using cloud fire store to store the current orders. I have a sub collection named orders and documents are auto generated and I have various fields such as name, email, address and status. The status while ordering will be 'waiting'. After ordering, the order will appear in the admin screen as I have connected it to a stream. If the admin accepts the order I want to update the status of the order to 'accepted', but in order to do so I need the document ID, but it is an auto generated one. Is there any method to retrieve this auto generated ID. If yes kindly help me.  If no kindly suggest me a method to retrieve the appropriate document ID for the appropriate order.

Thank you !

```dart
 class CurrentOrderStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime now = new DateTime.now();
    String date = "${now.day}-${now.month}-${now.year}";
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: firestore
          .collection('orders')
          .doc(date)
          .collection('orders')
          .where('status', isEqualTo: 'waiting')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }

        List<CurrentOrderCard> currentOrderCardWidget = [];
        final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
        for (var i in messages) {
          print(i['name']);
          print(i['email']);
          print(i['order']);
          print(i['mobileNumber']);
          print(i['count']);
          print(i['type']);
          print(i['total']);
          print(i['deliveryAddress']);
          print(i['url']);
          String _order = i['order'].toString().replaceAll('[', '');
          String _count = i['count'].toString().replaceAll('[', '');
          String _type = i['type'].toString().replaceAll('[', '');
          String _url = i['url'].toString().replaceAll('[', '');
          _url = _url.toString().replaceAll(']', '');
          _count = _count.toString().replaceAll(']', '');
          _type = _type.toString().replaceAll(']', '');
          _order = _order.toString().replaceAll(']', '');

          print(_count);
          print(_order);
          print(_type);
          print(_url);

          currentOrderCardWidget.add(CurrentOrderCard(
            name: i['name'],
            address: i['deliveryAddress'],
            email: i['email'],
            order: _order,
            mobileNumber: i['mobileNumber'],
          ));
        }
        return ListView(
          children: currentOrderCardWidget,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class CurrentOrderCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final name;
  final mobileNumber;
  final address;
  final order;
  final email;
  final count;
  final type;
  final total;
  final url;
  CurrentOrderCard(
      {this.name,
      this.order,
      this.mobileNumber,
      this.address,
      this.email,
      this.count,
      this.total,
      this.type,
      this.url});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      elevation: 20,
      color: Colors.transparent,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 10),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), color: containerColor),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Order',
                style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                    fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Text(order, style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 12)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Text('Delivery Address',
                style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(
                    fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Text(address, style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 12)),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Divider(
              thickness: 2,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 5,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Colors.red),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('DECLINE'),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.cancel,
                        size: 20,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith(
                        (states) => Colors.green),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Text('ACCEPT'),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5,
                      ),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        size: 20,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you simply asking how to get the ID of a document from the snapshot of the query results?

Comment: Yes, how shall I retrieve the ID of the Document.